# PHP: Can't figure out how to translate the name of a multilevel variable into a string?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to write a PHP script to install in my local machine's crontab that will:

1) Log into a remote FTP server
2) Retrieve a list of files
3) Download any files which have been created since today at 12:00AM.

I have been able to hash together some code examples and get closer to my intended result. However, I have become rather stuck on one point. In order to get the files which are new, I have had to use ftp_rawlist function. This returns a nested array, where each file is represented as an array containing elements that represent its properties (user, group, size, etc). I am able to interact with the items of the array, but once I have found an "array" that I want to download, I am having a hard time doing that.

**The code**

```
<?php 

    // define function to sync directory structure via ftp;

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    chdir('/Users/robotlaptop/Desktop/phpfiles');

    // define some login credentials
    $ftp_username = 'xxx';
    $ftp_userpass = 'xxx';
    $ftp_server = 'xxx';
    // set up a connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
    $sync_compare = date('d M');

    // set passive mode on
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

        function listDetailed($resource, $directory = '.') { 
            if (is_array($children = @ftp_rawlist($resource, $directory))) { 
                $items = array(); 
                global $conn_id;
                global $sync_compare;
                foreach ($children as $child) { 
                    $chunks = preg_split("/\s+/", $child); 
                    list($item['rights'], $item['number'], $item['user'], $item['group'], $item['size'], $item['month'], $item['day'], $item['time']) = $chunks; 
                    $item['type'] = $chunks[0]{0} === 'd' ? 'directory' : 'file'; 
                    array_splice($chunks, 0, 8); 
                    $items[implode(" ", $chunks)] = $item; 
                    $synctest = $item['day'] . ' ' . $item['month'];

                    if ($sync_compare == $synctest ) {
                        ftp_get($conn_id, 'testfile', $file, FTP_BINARY);
                        }


                    }

                return $items; 
            } 

            // Throw exception or return false < up to you 
        } 


    $testme = listDetailed($conn_id, '/');

    print_r($testme);
    //print_r($testme);

    ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

The problem from above is most specifically that I am unable to figure out how to pass in the name of the array which represents the file name into the third parameter given to the ftp_get function appearing inside of the loop. I have tried changing $file to $items, which makes sense conceptually, except that's the name of an array so it doesn't work. If I'm guessing correctly, I need to figure out how to get a variable that will represent the string of the file name. If you look at the output of the print_r (below), you will see that each file name is mapped to a key value.

Sorry if this question is so elementary; I am new to programming.

**Output of** `print_r($testme)`

```
    Array
    (
        [dandelions.txt] => Array
            (
                [time] => 16:12
                [day] => 12
                [month] => Mar
                [size] => 21
                [group] => 0
                [user] => 0
                [number] => 1
                [rights] => -rw-r--r--
                [type] => file
            )

        [goobs.txt] => Array
            (
                [time] => 21:34
                [day] => 29
                [month] => Nov
                [size] => 31
                [group] => 0
                [user] => 0
                [number] => 1
                [rights] => -rw-r--r--
                [type] => file
            )

    )
```

Comment: looking for array function [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)?

Comment: Just FYI, starting your question off with **Probably A Dumb Question** makes me much less motivated to continue reading.

Comment: No place for pathos on SO :)  Stick to logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access array key in foreach as following, assuming files array is `$files`:

```
foreach ($files as $file_name => $file_info) {

 ...

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get just the keys of the array, you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/array-keys).

For example:

```
$array = [
    'hello.txt' => [
        'somerandomdata',
        'somemorerandomdata',
        'evenmore'
    ],
    'newfile.txt' => [
        'blah',
        'randomdata'
    ]
];
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello.txt
    [1] => newfile.txt
)
```